# PHP Imagemagick PDF to GIF

Tags: php, linux, imagemagick

I have the following code which is supposed to convert the first page of PDF to thumbnail:

```
<?php
$strPDF = "http://www.domain.com/b.pdf";
exec("/usr/bin/convert \"{$strPDF}[0]\" -colorspace RGB -geometry 200 \"output.gif\"");
?>
```

My host server is Siteground, and apparently /usr/bin/convert is where ImageMagick convert function is.  This is my first time using ImageMagick and I'm not sure if it is doing anything.  Is my code correct?  And if it is, I can't seem to find output.gif.

Answer (score 0):

Give the output file a full path. Example : /home/marlboro/www/output.gif

Also, first download the PDF to your local machine (use curl/wget).

Before using exec from PHP you should be 100% sure the method works when called manually from shell!